# Turn off parse push status

Tags: swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

Is there anyway to turn off recording or clear all of the _PushStatus class? It is getting very large and I will never need it.

I have already tried:
*query from IOS app, the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` method gives empty data.
*query from cloud code funtion, also empty results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to turn it off for the moment. You can open a pull request to add that option, or periodically drop the table from your MongoDB database.

You can put a TTL on a collection right through an index.

We cap the collection size to objects that are less than a month old, and it's working flawlessly:

```
{
  "v": 1,
  "key": {
    "_created_at": 1
  },
  "name": "_created_at_1",
  "ns": "parse-ampme-prod._PushStatus",
  "background": true,
  "expireAfterSeconds": 2592000
}
```

You can create such an index using:

```
db.["_PushStatus"].createIndex( { "_created_at": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600  } );
```

This will automatically delete all objects that are older than an hour, and you can adapt it to your needs.

Comment: That's what I've heard online, but could you answer how to do that in your answer.

Comment: with the mongo client:

`db["_PushStatus"].drop()`

Comment: this doesn't work... at least for me. Even when I type: show collections, it returns nothing... any ideas?

Comment: Would just hitting the trashcan icon next to _PushStatus in my mLab database do the same thing? Or could that cause unintended side effects?

Comment: @flovilmart What would be the minimum time a doc in `_PushStatus` should be kept? I assume the push status can be updated over a period of time when the Apple or Firebase push notification service has retries, etc.

Comment: The services will never callback on the server, so you can keep them as long as you see fit